# Field is not visible in lightning page but is visible in classic

Tags: custom-field, page-layout

I have created 2 new fields in Object lead and added 2 new fileds in the page layout also. But after entering any value from web to lead the data and the field itself is not visible in salesforce lightning but the same is visible in salesforce classic. Also I have created a seperate page layout for the same object and added the same new 2 fields and assigned the layout to System admin but still the page layout is not visible in salesforce lightning but is visible in Salesforce classic. So could you please help me in this or provide me steps for the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With LEX it's entirely possible your changes aren't showing because you're viewing a cached version of the layout.

Comment: actually this layout is for standard object lead so that is the reason i guess i am not getting Field option in lightning app builder page